# Creation of PyTuple in C++ module crashes

Tags: python, python-c-api

Having some trouble with this code. Trying to return a tuple of tuples (coordinates) from a C++ module Im writing. It looks right to me, the `dirty` list contains two `Coord`s so `len` is 2, the `x` and `y` values of the items in the list are `0,0` and `0,1` respectively. First time Im attempting this so I might very well have misunderstood the docs or something. Any hints?

```
PyObject* getDirty()
{
    int len = dirty.size();
    PyObject* tuple = PyTuple_New(len);
    int count = 0;
    for (std::list<Coord>::iterator i = dirty.begin(); i != dirty.end(); ++i)
    {
        PyTuple_SET_ITEM(tuple, count, PyTuple_Pack(2, (*i).x, (*i).y));
        ++count;
    }
    return tuple;
}
```

**Edit:** Oh, forgot to mention, the actual crash is on the `PyTuple_Set_ITEM` line.

Comment: Use `i->x` instead of `(*i).x`.

Comment: Got it, looks better... but is there any other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `PyTuple_Pack`, after the first one, must be `PyObject` pointers.

You might want instead

```
Py_BuildValue("(ii)", (*i).x, (*i).y)
```

...assuming the coordinates are actually of type `int`.

Comment: Yes, just found that out through some crazy experimentation. Although, I do it with the format string "(i,i)" is that wrong? And, btw, you dont happen to know the difference? PyTuple_Pack seems to return a PyObject* (which was created) so I cant see why that didnt work.

Comment: The relevant difference between Py_BuildValue and PyTuple_Pack is that Py_BuildValue converts each individual value to a `PyObject*` for you, whereas PyTuple_Pack expects each of its arguments to already be a `PyObject*`.